# Leaflet Markercluster with GeoJson and Leaflet Ajax

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Referring to the examples in a previous question: [Leaflet MarkerCluster with GeoJson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824478/leaflet-markercluster-with-geojson/29856139#29856139)

I am trying to use markercluster with leaflet after the geojson data has been loaded, I can see the data is loading along with the markercluster markers from the console but it looks like the final map.addLayer is failing, the browser just seems to hang when it gets to this point.

I am able to load up and display the map points after the geojson is loaded with geojsonAjax.addTo(map); so this part is working.

the leaflet library and plugins are loaded in the following order:

```
leaflet.js
leaflet.ajax.min.js
leaflet.markercluster.js



    // Add basemap tiles and attribution.
    var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    });


    // Create map and set center and zoom.

    var map = L.map('map', {
      scrollWheelZoom: false,
      center: [47.5, 10],
      zoom: 5
    });

    // Add basemap to map.
    map.addLayer(OpenStreetMap_Mapnik);

    var geojsonAjax = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("/campaign-results/geojson", {
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return new L.marker(latlng);
      },
    });
    //geojsonAjax.addTo(map);
    //map.addLayer(geojsonAjax);
    //console.log("data loaded:", geojsonAjax);

  var markers = L.markerClusterGroup()


  //geojson ajax listener
  geojsonAjax.on('data:loaded', function () {
    // Add the cluster data after the geojson layer has loaded.
    markers.addLayer(geojsonAjax);
    console.log("add markers:", markers);
    map.addLayer(markers);
  });
```

Comment: It seems like the size of geojson data is too big, I tested it wit a smaller file and it seems to work other than the markerclusters not displaying correctly which is probably a css issue, is there any way of using markercluster with the larger geojson data?

Comment: Welcome to SO! "_the size of geojson data is too big_": what file size? How many point feature? Any non point geometry? What version of Leaflet.markercluster?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! The size of the json file is 1.07mb, there are 1248 points and no non point geometry. The version of Leaflet.Markercluster is 1.6.0. I also tried adding "chunkedLoading: true" and "chunkInterval: 100" to the L.markerClusterGroup but this didn't work.

Comment: Hum very strange indeed... there is nothing suspicious in your code, and your data is not that big. Please would you be able to share a live reproduction example, e.g. using http://leafletjs.com/edit ?

Comment: I have fixed the problem, it was bad data. Users had entered a number of coordinates wrong and they were missing the decimal which was causing markercluster to hang.

Comment: So for example they had entered coords of 7109, 50768 but they should have been 7.109, 50.768 https://plnkr.co/edit/PCmzNsML1SXhD24R